# How can I install avant window navigator in 12.10?

Tags: installation, software-center, awn

Installing the ubuntu 11.10 packages works.I can't compile awn on ubuntu 12.10. And i can't install it with the software-center but the program is listed on it. It isn't like awn depends to 100 % on vala, so all non vala written parts of awn schould be runnable on ubuntu 12.10 too.

Comment: This is not an anwser to your question but DockbarX standalone dock has gotten support for applets and the intention is to make an option for people who used to use DockbarX + AWN. It doesn't have nearly as many applets as AWN but it has the basics (cardapio menu, appindicators, clock, volume control). AWN applets written in python can relatively easy be ported to DockbarX (as volume control is). DockbarX 0.90.1 was released yesterday and will be in dockbarx ppa some times next week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWN is now available in the main WebUpd8 PPA for Ubuntu 12.10 so you can install it using the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install avant-window-navigator
```

from [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/how-to-install-avant-window-navigator.html)

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing . But since it is your blog , you should mention it in the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

It has been dropped from Quantal:

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12299402&postcount=25)

> Some applications including Avant Window Navigator behave erratically.
>
> AWN has been dropped from Ubuntu as it is unmaintained and no longer builds from source with current versions of vala.

You can install the 12.04 version from [here](http://nc.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/avant-window-navigator/avant-window-navigator_0.4.1%7Ebzr830-2ubuntu1_i386.deb)
In case you need dependencies find it from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=avant-window-navigator)

However - given the warning from Jeremy Bicha and the original OP - the advise is to switch to another dock such as Docky

Answer (score 0):

You can install AWN on 12.10 without crawling around the net collecting dependencies by temporarily using the repositories from 12.04:

1) create the file **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise.list** with the following contents:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

3) `sudo apt-get update`

4) `sudo apt-get install avant-window-navigator awn-applets-all`

5) remove the file **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise.list**

6) `sudo apt-get update`

(EDIT: simplified instructions)